# Add multiple strings as single string into list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have applied the `beautifulsoup` library for parsing certain webpages. So, my query for extracting article is:

```
for i in a.findAll("p"):
      print (i.text)
```

and , I got the output as:

```
Paragraph 1
Paragraph 2
Paragraph 3
```

Now, I'm handling the multiple webpages and all I want to append single webpage article parapgraphs into the list as single string element. Something as:

```
['Paragraph 1 Paragraph 2 Paragraph 3']
```

What I have done is:

```
string_list=[i.text for i in a.findAll("p")]
```

This gives as:

```
print (string_list)
['Paragraph1','Paragraph2','Paragraph3']
```

Comment: Use str.join --> `" ".join(i.text for i in a.findAll("p"))`?

Comment: Try this:
```" ".join(['Paragraph1','Paragraph2','Paragraph3']```

Answer (score 0):

```
bs4_p_tags= a.findAll("p")
this_page=[]
for i in bs4_p_tags:
    this_page.append(i.text)
common_this_page_para=[]
single_string=" ".join(this_page)# joins the string elements of iterable with single space as separator. 
common_this_page_para.append(single_string)
```

please don't mind long variable names, these are just to make it self explanatory.